# Migrating server - User/Passwords & Schema

Tags: iccube

I created a schema as admin in my old iccube install. I would like to restore this schema in my new version of iccube installed on an other server.

Which folder need I to copy in order to restore this schema in my new version?

By the way, I forgot my admin password on the old install. Can I change my password in some config files?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the default authentication system user/passwords are saved into a local file, icCubeUsers.icc-users, located in the {iccube-install}/security/users directory.

Easy solution, copy the file from the old to the new.

Complicated one :

The file contains lines like this one :

```
<user uuid="527aa50e-8704-4b1d-9ade-ed11131ac7b3" name="demo" password="" hash="eh4tWYDK0zOn10dXInW3Rk68KbowXfxf1r5btmnK+4c=$0pnhp/LC4+5MXkEqVEP5Pcwzf1NpZPOuTq00VdJZG6w=">
    <role>standard</role>
    <locale>en</locale>
</user>
```

There should be no way to reverse the password but you can copy & paste from a known one.

the password for this hash

eh4tWYDK0zOn10dXInW3Rk68KbowXfxf1r5btmnK+4c=$0pnhp/LC4+5MXkEqVEP5Pcwzf1NpZPOuTq00VdJZG6w=

is iccube

Restart icCube login and feel free to change the password

Answer (score 2):

Using the UI, I would export the schema from the "old" server and then import it into the "new" server. Am I missing something ?